# How can the Flask development server handle so many requests concurrently?

Tags: flask

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test_speed', methods=['GET'])
def test_speed():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 'Blah'
```

When I run the above on a uWSGI server it handles a number of requests concurrently equal to the number of workers specified, which makes sense. I've been doing the tests with JMeter. So for example if I have 8 workers in the uWSGI server, every 3 seconds I get 8 more requests handled.

I was trying to compare this to the Flask development server. The development server seems to handle far more requests concurrently (1000's). For example, if I send 1000 requests at once, all of them get handled after 3 seconds, whereas with the uWSGI server it would take ceil(1000/8)*3 to complete handling all the requests. I'm trying to understand why the development server is able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I guess I figured out the answer to my question: My test using sleep() wasn't good, because sleep releases the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). By releasing the GIL the dev server is able to quickly move onto other requests while the previous ones are sleeping. If instead of sleep(3) I do something like the following, which is more representative of an actual blocking operation, I get expected behavior:

```
delay = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=3)
while datetime.now() < delay:
  continue
```